# Angular: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My angular app is structured in a header, main and footer surrounded by a div.
Depending on the height of the header (it is responsive) I have to set a padding-top on the surrounding div.

To do this, I added an input parameter called height to my header.component which I pass from my app.component.
On window:resize I set the value of this parameter to the elements offsetHeight and emit this change so that the app.component recognize it.
I also set the height ngOnInit to give it an initial height.

This works great apart from the error I get in console:

```
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '160'.
  at viewDebugError (core.js:9514)
  at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:9492)
  at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9661)
  at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:13672)
  at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:13646)
  at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:14454)
  at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14356)
  at Object.View_AppComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:2)
  at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14338)
  at checkNoChangesView (core.js:13486)
```

Can anybody help me with this error?

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="stage" [style.padding-top.px]="this.headerHeight">
  <app-header [(height)]="this.headerHeight"></app-header>
  ...
</div>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { OverlayComponent } from './../overlay/overlay.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() height: number;
  @Output() heightChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changeHeight()
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  changeHeight(): void {
    this.height = this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.heightChange.emit(this.height);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you need to inform the parent of the height, wrapping `setTimeout` around `this.changeHeight()` should trigger change detection again.  @GünterZöchbauer has an elegant solution but I'm not sure if it will only update the current component and its children.

Comment: read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) and let us know what's unclear

Answer (score 3):

Angular doesn't like when the model changes when `ngOnInit()` is called.
Invoke change detection explicitly after the change to get rid of the error

```ts
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() height: number;
  @Output() heightChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef, private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changeHeight();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // <<<=== added
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  changeHeight(): void {
    this.height = this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.heightChange.emit(this.height);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems cleaner than wrapping `this.changeHeight()` in `setTimeout`. Are there other advantages?

Comment: `setTimeout` runs change detection on the whole application, `detectChanges` only on the component (and it's descendants).

Comment: Thank you. In this case, it looks like `changeHeight()` informs the parent of the new height. Will it still work if only the current component and children are updated?

Comment: Right, missed that one. I don't know by heart what happens when an EventEmitter emits an event in `ngOnInit()`. In this case it's probably better to use `setTimeout`. Should be easy to find out though if it works with `detectChanges`.